# How to listen routing in service Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have service in Angular where I try to listen route:

```
@Injectable()
export class TabService implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    })
  }

}
```

It gives me empty result always when URL is changed, in line: `console.log(params);`

Also I tried to move listening to `ngOnInit() {}`.

**Routing is:**

```
{ path: "dictionary", component: SkeletonComponent, children: [ { path: ":code", component: DictionaryComponent }]`
```

**Listening is:**

```
constructor(_route: ActivatedRoute) {
  _route
    .queryParamMap
    .subscribe(params => console.log(params.get('code')));
}
```

So, I can not get `code` parameter

Comment: Why exactly should a service listen to a route change? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need service that listen route and activate tabs in each components where they are

Comment: Why not do that in the component itself?

Comment: It is duplicated code, I need separated logical service, class that does it

Comment: Well, I'm not sure whether that is the way to go about it. For instance, say you are able to make your service get the routing info - now what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect URL changes, you need to subscribe to `router events` like:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
          if(event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url) {
            console.log(event.url);
          }
        });
}
```

`this.activatedRoute.paramMap` is used to get `Url parameters`

Comment: How to get parameters?

Comment: What you did in your question is right just use this to get desired param . `params['paramName']`

Comment: Could you modify your answer, please

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get specifically the query parameters? Otherwise you can try something like:

```js
constructor(_router: Router) {
  _router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
      // do something when a module start loading for the first time
    } else if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
      // do something when a module finished loading for the first time
    } else  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // you can get the url with event.url;
    } else if(...) { 
      // you can test for any event described in https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

    }
  });
}
```

If you want to listen specifically to query params change:

```js
constructor(_route: ActivatedRoute) {
  _route
    .paramMap
    .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => console.log(params.get('code')));
}
```

Comment: It does not return me parameter

Comment: My route is: ` {
    path: "dictionary",
    component: SkeletonComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ":code",
        component: DictionaryComponent
      }]`

Comment: Listenng is: ` activateRoute
    .queryParamMap
    .subscribe(params => console.log(params.get('code')));`

Comment: In your case, it's a path variable. So you really need `paramMap` instead of `queryParamMap`. I'll update my answer (apparently it'll be like your first try).